# Column with multiple data types in Power BI Matrix Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

My issue is similar to this one [Multiple data types in a Power BI matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60383602/multiple-data-types-in-a-power-bi-matrix) but I've got a bit of a different setup that's throwing everything off.

What I'm trying to do is create a matrix table with several metrics that are categorized as Current (raw data values) and Prior (year over year percent growth/decline). I've created some dummy data in Excel to get the format the way I want it in PowerBI (see below):

[Desired Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCEsV.png)

As you can see the Current values are coming in as integers and the Prior % numbers as percentages which is exactly what I want; however, I was able to accomplish this through a custom column with the following formula:

```
Revenue2 = IF(Scorecard2[Current_Prior] = "Current", FORMAT(FIXED(Scorecard2[Revenue],0), "$#,###"), FORMAT(Scorecard2[Revenue], "Percent"))
```

The problem is that the data comes from a SQL query and you can't use the FORMAT() function in DirectQuery. Is there a way I can have two different datatypes in the same column of data? See below for how the SQL data comes into PowerBI (I can change this if need be):

[SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g7uG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 separate measures, one for the Current second for Prior, and format these measures.
Probably you can also use a case in SQL query to format your data to bring it as STRING.

Comment: If I do this then I will have two Revenue metrics appear in the rows. I need it to just be one.

Comment: IF you want only one and you dont want to aggregate this column then format whole column in sql using cast and case (and return as string)

Answer (score 0):

What I wound up doing was reformatting the SQL code to look like this:

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l4ih.png)

That way Current/Prior are have two separate values and the "metric" is categorical.

I got the idea from this post:
[Simple way to transpose columns and rows in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql)